# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'variations')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have my chrome extension listing errors on the extensions tab, but it's not completing the code that i'm using the try/catch.

In this code if the responseText does not contain ant variations, chrome shows the Uncaught TypeError, but does NOT run the catch console.log

```
try{
   $price_test =http.responseText;
   var txt = http.response;
   var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
   var prueba = obj.result.variations[0];
}catch (error) {
   console.log('error')
}
```

How can i get the try/catch to actualy catch the error instead of chrome stoping the code there.

Comment: You can check if the object you JSON-parsed from HTTP response is what you expected. After `var obj = JSON.parse(txt)` you can use something like `if (!obj.result || !obj.result.variations) throw new Error('no variations!');`

Comment: You probably look at an old error. Click the clear button and retry.